# Numpy significantly slower on Windows than on Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, numpy, performance, ubuntu

I ran the following snippet in IPython on both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on the same machine (dual-boot):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((1280, 1024))
b = np.random.random((1280, 1024))

%timeit a / b
```

On Windows, this outputs:

```
1.81 ms ± 21.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

On Ubuntu, the output is:

```
649 µs ± 1.41 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I see the same performance difference with all basic arithmetic operations.

On both systems, I'm running this in a conda environment, with Python 3.8.3, NumPy 1.19.2 and MKL 2020.1. The machine runs AMD Ryzen 9 5950X CPU.

Why is there such a big discrepancy between the two systems? Are there ways to bring performance on Windows closer to Ubuntu?

Comment: You compiled both of them with the MKL yourself, with identical parameters, using the same compiler and version?

Comment: No. I installed it with conda on both systems.

Comment: Note that the MKL should not be used for such a computation in Numpy -- Numpy use its own implementation. The compiler and the compilation flags can strongly impact the performance. Note also we have improved the performance of Numpy very recently (thanks to a more SIMD-friendly implementation). It may be interesting for you to use the latest versions (the next major one should improve performance of such operation).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I tried NumPy version 1.22.3 (with and without MKL) from pip and conda and still seeing the same discrepancy. By the latest version, do you mean the development version on GitHub?

Comment: @JaroslawM.Blusewicz Ok. Interesting. Yes, it would be great if you can test the development version (on github) since an important change on such a computation is not yet included in the public releases.